# Data frame subsetting under multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame containing information about top two candidates for local elections in Brazil that looks like this:

```
Name <- c('Andressa', 'Marcos', 'Anderson', 'Cibelle', 'Ivy', 'Eliana')
Municipality <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
Gender <- c('F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F')
Vote_Share <- c(51, 49, 55, 45, 70, 30)
data <- data.frame(Name, Municipality, Gender, Vote_Share)

Name       Municipality   Gender   Vote_Share 
Andressa         A           F         51
Marcos           A           M         49
Anderson         B           M         55
Cibelle          B           F         45
Ivy              C           F         70
Eliana           C           F         30
```

I want to keep in my data only the information about the municipalities where the race is one man against a woman.

So, I'm looking for an output like this:

```
Name       Municipality   Gender   Vote_Share 
Andressa         A           F         51
Marcos           A           M         49
Anderson         B           M         55
Cibelle          B           F         45
```

Furthermore I want to create another object containing the win margin for women (vote share for woman - vote share for man) in elections for each municipalitie:

```
Municipality     Win Margin
A                    2
B                    10
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'Municipality' and `filter` those groups having two distinct 'Gender' values

```
library(dplyr)
out1 <- data %>%
           group_by(Municipality) %>%
           filter(n_distinct(Gender) == 2)
out1
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Municipality [2]
#  Name     Municipality Gender Vote_Share
#  <fct>    <fct>        <fct>       <dbl>
#1 Andressa A            F              51
#2 Marcos   A            M              49
#3 Anderson B            M              55
#4 Cibelle  B            F              45
```

Or specify both the 'levels' are in the 'Gender'

```
data %>%
    group_by(Municipality) %>%
    filter(all(c("M", "F") %in% Gender))
```

---

Once we get the first summarised output

```
out1 %>%
   summarise(WinMargin = abs(diff(Vote_Share)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Municipality WinMargin
#  <fct>            <dbl>
#1 A                    2
#2 B                   10
```

---

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[uniqueN(Gender) == 2)], .(Municipality)
     ][, .(WinMargin = abs(diff(Vote_Share))), by = Municipality]
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can make use `subset` with `table`

```
subset(data, Municipality %in%  names(which(rowSums(table(Municipality,
         Gender) > 0) > 1)))
#      Name Municipality Gender Vote_Share
#1 Andressa            A      F         51
#2   Marcos            A      M         49
#3 Anderson            B      M         55
#4  Cibelle            B      F         45
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, using `subset()` + `ave()`

```
dfout <- subset(df,as.logical(ave(Gender,Municipality,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))==2)))
```

or

```
dfout <- subset(df,as.logical(ave(Gender,Municipality,FUN = function(x) !any(duplicated(x)))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
      Name Municipality Gender Vote_Share
1 Andressa            A      F         51
2   Marcos            A      M         49
3 Anderson            B      M         55
4  Cibelle            B      F         45
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `factor`ize then `as.numeric`, take the `mean` and exclude where it's not `1`.

```
dat[with(dat, ave(as.numeric(as.factor(Gender)), Municipality)) != 1, ]
#       Name Municipality Gender Vote_Share
# 1 Andressa            A      F         51
# 2   Marcos            A      M         49
# 3 Anderson            B      M         55
# 4  Cibelle            B      F         45
```

Curiously this also works, because `F` is shorthand of `FALSE` and `F` together with `M` makes no sense --> `NA`, which we can exclude.

```
dat[is.na(with(dat, ave(as.logical(Gender), Municipality))), ]
#       Name Municipality Gender Vote_Share
# 1 Andressa            A      F         51
# 2   Marcos            A      M         49
# 3 Anderson            B      M         55
# 4  Cibelle            B      F         45
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Anderson", 
"Andressa", "Cibelle", "Eliana", "Ivy", "Marcos"), class = "factor"), 
    Municipality = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Vote_Share = c(51, 49, 55, 45, 70, 30)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `ave` and `subset` in base R

```
temp <- subset(data, as.logical(ave(Gender, Municipality, FUN = function(x) 
                all(c('F', 'M') %in% x))))

#      Name Municipality Gender Vote_Share
#1 Andressa            A      F         51
#2   Marcos            A      M         49
#3 Anderson            B      M         55
#4  Cibelle            B      F         45
```

and then use `aggregate` to calculate the difference in vote.

```
aggregate(Vote_Share~Municipality, temp, function(x) diff(range(x)))

#  Municipality Vote_Share
#1            A          2
#2            B         10
```